# Can I work as an online freelance developer, even if I don't speak English, but I can read, write, and understand it perfectly?

Tags: freelance-websites, freelance

I can write and understand English perfectly, but unfortunately I'm weak at speaking it due to a lack of practice.

I have a couple of years of experience in both full-stack web and desktop dev. I'm also not afraid to learn new things as long as it pays.

So is it possible for me to work as a developer on freelance platforms regardless of my limitation? If yes, then can you give advice on how?

Comment: Sure , you can.

Answer (score 1):

English speaking skill is normally not a requirement in freelance marketplaces. Although, it can provide an absolute edge as many clients would ask for an interview / on-boarding call.

You can definitely start your journey without conversing in English. However, consider English as another tool in your basket of must-have tools of the trade. There are so many apps available that can help you improve your English speaking skills.

Comment: Some people just literally watch TV to learn the language, baseball players have successfully done that.